# Wait for object array to load and map() it. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to loop through json_obj after it loads using async `XMLHttpRequest()` but as json_obj is null at the start map() crashes.

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class ImageViewer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            json_obj : null,
            link: "https://api.github.com/users/github/repos"
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", this.state.link, true);
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    this.setState({ json_obj :JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).sort(function(a, b){var keyA = new Date(a.updated_at),keyB = new Date(b.updated_at);if(keyA > keyB) return -1;if(keyA < keyB) return 1;return 0;})});
                } else {
                console.error(xhr.statusText);
                }
            }
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(xhr.statusText);
        };
        xhr.send(null);
    }
    render() {
    return (
            <div>
                {this.state.json_obj.map((obj, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div >
                                    <h1>{obj.name}</h1>
                                    <h1>{obj.updated_at}</h1>
                                </div>
                            )
                })}
            </div>
    )
}}
ReactDOM.render(
  <ImageViewer />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
: <div id="root"></div>
```

I tried to use conditional rendering but it throws errors as well:

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class ImageViewer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            json_obj : null,
            link: "https://api.github.com/users/github/repos",
            stuff : {name:"loading", updated_at:"loading"}
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", this.state.link, true);
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    this.setState({ json_obj :JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).sort(function(a, b){var keyA = new Date(a.updated_at),keyB = new Date(b.updated_at);if(keyA > keyB) return -1;if(keyA < keyB) return 1;return 0;})});
                } else {
                console.error(xhr.statusText);
                }
            }
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(xhr.statusText);
        };
        xhr.send(null);
    }
    render() {
    return (
            <div>
                {(this.state.json_obj ? this.state.json_obj : this.state.stuff).map((obj, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div >
                                    <h1>{obj.name}</h1>
                                    <h1>{obj.updated_at}</h1>
                                </div>
                            )
                })}
            </div>
    )
}}
ReactDOM.render(
  <ImageViewer />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: What error(s) are you receiving?

Comment: json_obj is not defined/null. @Dominic Tobias solution worked. Just cannot accept it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So check if it's null and return something else:

```
if (!this.state.json_obj) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
}

return (
  <div>
    {this.state.json_obj.map((obj, index) => (
      <div key={obj.name}>
        <h1>{obj.name}</h1>
        <h1>{obj.updated_at}</h1>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

Your code was throwing because `this.state.stuff` is an object and you can't iterate over an object with `.map`. If `this.state.json_obj` is also an object and not an array you would need to do `Object.keys(this.state.json_obj).map(...`.

Answer (score 1):

The first code you provided throws an error because `json_obj` is `null` as you mentioned. But the second one throws an error because you are trying to `map` over the object `this.state.stuff` which you can not do. So there are actually a couple of things you can do:

wrap `stuff` inside an array:

```
return (
            <div>
                {(this.state.json_obj ? this.state.json_obj : [this.state.stuff]).map((obj, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div >
                                    <h1>{obj.name}</h1>
                                    <h1>{obj.updated_at}</h1>
                                </div>
                            )
                })}
            </div>
```

or you can wrap it when defining it:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        loading: true,
        json_obj : null,
        link: "https://api.github.com/users/github/repos",
        stuff : [{name:"loading", updated_at:"loading"}]
    }
}
```

or you can simply check if `json_obj` is available and rendering something else (or nothing) instead.

**renders nothing if `json_obj` is not available**

```
return (
            <div>
                {this.state.json_obj && this.state.json_obj.map((obj, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div >
                                    <h1>{obj.name}</h1>
                                    <h1>{obj.updated_at}</h1>
                                </div>
                            )
                })}
            </div>
    )
```

**renders a loading message when json_obj is not available**

```
return (
  <div>
    {
    this.state.json_obj ?
      this.state.json_obj.map((obj, index) => {
       return (
         <div >
           <h1>{obj.name}</h1>
           <h1>{obj.updated_at}</h1>
         </div>
       )
     }) : <div>Loading...</div>
    }
   </div>
  )
```

Comment: Really nice to get to know why stuff did not want to render and to get multiple solutions to problems. Thanks a lot.